# How to call function with argparse arguments in unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, argparse, python-unittest

Please help me to write the unit test to this:

I have a simple program with one function which returns only doubled "*name*" when run the program with argparse argument `--double`. Otherwise returns a single name

```py
    # code.py
    import argparse
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("name")
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--double', action="store_true")
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    def double_name(new_name):
      if args.double:
        return new_name + new_name
      else:
        return new_name
    
    print(double_name(args.name))
```

1. run in cmd `python code.py test-name` I have a result: `test-name`
2. run in cmd `python code.py test-name -d` I have a result: `test-nametest-name`

I want to write unittest to check this function, but I don't know **how to call this function with argparse arguments in unit test**.

```py
    # test_code.py
    import unittest
    import code
    
    class Test_Code(unittest.TestCase):
    
      def test_double_name(self):
        # without -d
        self.assertEqual(code.double_name('test-name'), 'test-name')
        # with -d
        self.assertEqual(code.double_name('test-name'), 'test-nametest-name')
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
```

How should look the run command this test? If I add to code:

```py
    code.args = code.parser.parse_args(["test-name", "-d"])
```

the standard commands `python -m unittest test_code.py` raise **AttributeError**

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'py'

Answer (score 0):

Do the accessing of parsed data outside of the function, and pass the data in. Then it doesn't matter where the data comes from:

```
def double_name(new_name, double):
  if double:
    return new_name + new_name
  else:
    return new_name

print(double_name(args.name, args.double))
```

Then:

```
self.assertEqual(code.double_name('test-name', False), 'test-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `parse_args` with your own list of arguments, letting it produce an appropriate value to use. This requires rewriting `code` slightly to avoid having it call `parse_arg` on import:

```
# code.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("name")
parser.add_argument('-d', '--double', action="store_true")


def double_name(new_name):
  if args.double:
    return new_name + new_name
  else:
    return new_name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(double_name(args.name))
```

Then

```
# test_code.py
import unittest
import code


class Test_Code(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_double_name(self):
    code.args = code.parser.parse_args([])
    self.assertEqual(code.double_name('test-name'), 'test-name')

    code.args = code.parser.parse_args(["-d"])
    self.assertEqual(code.double_name('test-name'), 'test-nametest-name')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

In your test function, you need to make sure that you set the value of `code.args`, since that's the variable used by `code.double_name`.